# Does pjsip support sending as well as receiving DTMF tones?

Tags: pjsip

I am working on a simple sipcall android app, but i wish to send as well as receive Dtmf . Android default sipstack doesnt support receving dtmf tone. so wish to ask does PJSIP support receiving dtmf tone during call as well.

Comment: Don't know Android sipstack, but I guess it is possible with PJSIP, eg. in PJSUA lib there are callbacks `on_dtmf_digit` and `on_dtmf_digit2` [link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__callback.htm#a16c678038d11cfa8a99e8595afce7fba)